# Extract a Value from the DOM

Tags: html, getelementsbyclassname, inspect

Q1) How do I get to '1' in the XML/HTML using the FindElement/By class?

```
<h3 class="lemon--h3__373c0__sQmiG heading--h3__373c0__1n4Of alternate__373c0__1uacp">1<!-- -->.&nbsp;<a class="lemon--a__373c0__IEZFH link__373c0__29943 link-color--blue-dark__373c0__1mhJo link-size--inherit__373c0__2JXk5" href="/biz/teds-montana-grill-larimer-square-denver?osq=Teds+Montana+Grill" target="" name="Ted’s Montana Grill - Larimer Square" rel="">Ted’s Montana Grill - Larimer Square</a></h3>
```

Q2) How can I get `Ted's Montana Grill` and `Aurora` from the xml below?
I managed to get `Ted’s Montana Grill`. However, Aurora is proving to be challenge.

Here is the URL - https://www.yelp.com/biz/teds-montana-grill-aurora-aurora?osq=Teds+Montana+Grill

```
<h1 class="biz-page-title embossed-text-white">Ted’s Montana Grill -</h1>
<div class="u-inline-block">
            <h1 class="biz-page-title embossed-text-white">Aurora</h1>
            <div class="u-inline-block">
```

Trying with FindElement/By

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("lemon--h3__373c0__sQmiG heading--h3__373c0__1n4Of alternate__373c0__1uacp");
```

Q2:

```
let items = document.getElementsByClassName("biz-page-title embossed-text-white");
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i].outerText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2) They both have the same class so you can just iterate over all the nodes returned by `getElementsByClassName`.  All you need to do is access the `textContent` property.

```
const titles = document.getElementsByClassName("biz-page-title");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(titles, function(el) {
    console.log(el.textContent);
})
```

1) Same thing for your first question: `const value = document.getElementsByClassName("lemon--h3__373c0__sQmiG heading--h3__373c0__1n4Of alternate__373c0__1uacp")[0].textContent;`